# Regarding minimal elementary generators for $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, matrix-theory

I have a result concerning the minimal number of **elementary** generators (and by this I mean generators which are elementary matrices) for $GL(3, \mathbb{Z})$. I'm currently working on extending the result to $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ and I'd like to know if someone already did this before I spend too much time on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: There are several related definitions of elementary matrices, would you specify? (1) matrices $e_{ij}(r)$ with $i\neq j$? (2) only those $e_{ij}(1)$? Since you want to generate $GL_n$ you probably have in mind those diagonal with a single $-1$ and other diagonal entries being 1?

Comment: What I mean by elementary matrices is exactly the three types of matrices presented in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix . :)

Comment: Yes I checked the wikipedia article, but wikipedia is not the bible, can change with time, and in related contexts I often hear variants of these definitions.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm totally on the same page with you on this one, I was just trying to clear the air. :)

Comment: Is the answer less than the obvious estimate of $n+1$ generators?

Comment: It is less than n+1, yes.

Comment: @YCor more exactly, the matrices I'm referring to are the row/ column switching matrix, the row/ column multiplying matrix (in this case, the only relevant one is the one which multiplies a row or column by -1) and row/ column addition matrix, i.e. the one which adds to column j column i multiplied by a certain integer or adds to line i line j multiplied by a certain integer.

Comment: For $n=3$ you claim that the answer is $<4$. So it's either 2 or 3. How do you get 3? Btw to avoid lengthy discussion and sentences, it might be useful to use notation, say $e_{ij}=I+E_{ij}$, $d_i=I-2E_{ii}$, $s_{ij}=I+E_{ij}+E_{ji}-E_{ii}-E_{jj}$.

Answer (score 6):

The optimal number is $n$. Write $d_i$ the diagonal matrix with $-1$ at position $ii$ and $1$ at other diagonal places. For $i\neq j$, write $P_{ij}$ the transposition matrix $i\leftrightarrow j$, and $e_{ij}=I+E_{ij}$.

First, as you observed, $n$ can be achieved. Indeed, $\langle e_{12},e_{21},P_{1j},3\le j\le n\rangle$ generate for all $n\ge 3$ (for $n=2$ take $e_{12},P_{12}$ instead). Indeed, for $i,j\ge 3$ we have $P_{1i}e_{12}P_{1i}=e_{i2}$,  $P_{1j}e_{21}P_{1j}=e_{2j}$ and for such $i,j$ with $i\neq j$ we get $e_{ij}=[e_{i2},e_{2j}]$, and for a single $i$ we get $e_{1i}=[e_{12},e_{2i}]$ and similarly get $e_{2i},e_{i1},e_{i2}$. So the group they generate contains all $e_{ij}$, $1\le i\neq j\le n$, which generates $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$; since we also have $P_{13}$ of determinant $-1$, this generates $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$.

Conversely let us check that $n$ cannot be improved. Consider a set $S$ consisting of $k$ such matrices (or their powers, to allow all $e_{ij}^k=1+kE_{ij}$). Consider the graph with vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and an edge from $i$ to $j$ whenever some matrix $P_{ij}$ or $e_{ij}$, $e_{ji}$ occurs; label this edge with the corresponding element of $S$. If this graph is not connected, clearly this does not generate (some nontrivial direct sum decomposition is preserved). If connected, after removing edges we get a tree, and which has one more vertex than edges. So, originally, the number $k'$ of edges (which is $\le k$) is $\ge n-1$. In case of equality $k'=n-1$, this is indeed a tree. If all edges are of the form $P_{ij}$, then the group generated by $S$ is finite. Otherwise, there is an edge $e_{ij}$. Consider the subtree "on the left", that is, all elements in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which are closer to $i$ than $j$ in this tree. It forms a nonempty proper subset $I$. Up to a permutation of indices (possibly changing the value of $i$), we can suppose that $I$ is an initial segment $\{1,\dots,i\}$. This yields a nontrivial block decomposition preserved by $S$ (all but $e_{ij}$ are block-diagonal and $e_{ij}$ is block-upper triangular). Hence if $S$ generates, then $k\ge n$. (This also shows that if $S$ generates an infinite subgroup acting irreducibly on $\mathbf{Q}^n$, then $k\ge n$.)

Comment: Since $d_i$ is not used anywhere but in its definition, we deduce that such element doesn’t belong to any minimal generating set of elementary matrices.

Comment: @LucGuyot I agree if you mean "in any generating set of minimal cardinal".

Comment: So we agree. (You already rectified it: "minimal generating set" in my comment is wrong and should be replaced by "generating set of minimal cardinality".)

Answer (score 0):

@YCor, for $n = 3$ the answer is yes and was proven today by Bogdan. The proof, in full details, has 8 pages. The 3 elementary matrices that generate $GL_3 (Z)$ are:  $T_{12} (1) := I_3 + e_{12}$, $P_{12}$ and $P_{23}$, where the last two matrices are obtained from $I_3$ switching rows 1 and 2 and respectively 2 and 3.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a link to the paper or its preprint if it is already available.

Comment: 8 pages? if true, probably far from optimal: it suffices to write each of $e_{23}$ and $e_{31}$ as an expression of these 3 matrices (I write $e_{ij}=I+E_{ij}$ what you call $I+e_{ij}$).

Comment: $P_{12}e_{12}P_{12}=e_{21}$; $P_{23}e_{12}P_{23}=e_{13}$, $P_{12}e_{13}P_{12}=e_{23}$, $P_{23}e_{23}P_{23}=e_{32}$, $P_{12}e_{32}P_{12}=e_{31}$. So $\langle e_{12,}P_{12},P_{23}\rangle$ contain all $e_{ij}$, which generate $SL_3(Z)$. Since it also contains a matrix of determinant $-1$, it equals $GL_3(Z)$. This fits in a comment!

Comment: @YCor what doesn't fit in a comment is the reason why three is the minimal number of elementary generators

Comment: Yes, that three cannot be improved fits in a comment :) you have to check no pair generates among the $P_{ij},e_{ij},d_j$. To generate, it should involve all indices. So up to a permutation, we have $(P_{12},d_3)$, $(E_{12},d_3)$, $(E_{12},E_{23})$, $(E_{12},P_{23})$, $(P_{12},P_{23})$. All are contained in a block triangular subgroup, except the last pair, which is contained in a copy of the group of permutations. So none generates.